# Resolve one of multiple registrations with DryIoc

Tags: c#, ioc-container, dryioc

Given the small example below, is there a way to mark (attribute, name convention,... ) the `MyInterface` argument in `MyService2`, so that it will resolve correctly, or is the only way to pass in `MyInterface[]` ?
I know that Castle Windsor can resolve it based on naming convention, but I haven't found something similar in DryIoc

```
public interface MyInterface { }

public class MyImplementationA : MyInterface { }

public class MyImplementationB : MyInterface { }

public class MyService1
{
    public MyService1(MyInterface[] implementations) {
        Console.WriteLine(implementations.GetType().Name);
    }
}

public class MyService2
{
    public MyService2(MyInterface implementationA) {
        Console.WriteLine(implementationA.GetType().Name);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new Container();
        c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationA>(serviceKey: "implementationA");
        c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationB>(serviceKey: "implementationB");

        c.Register<MyService1>();
        c.Register<MyService2>();

        var a = c.Resolve<MyService1>();
        var b = c.Resolve<MyService2>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Figured out a way to do it at registration time:

c.Register<MyService2>(made: Made.Of(() => new  MyService2(Arg.Of<MyInterface>(ServiceKeys.ImplementationA))));

Comment: There are number if ways. The way with keys is probably a most deterministic and a safe bet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are number of ways:

#### First by using service keys as in your comment

Here the consumer selects dependency based on key.

```
c.Register<MyService2>(made: Made.Of(() => 
    new MyService2(Arg.Of<MyInterface>(ServiceKeys.ImplementationA))));
```

**update:** or in constructor agnostic way

```
c.Register<MyService2>(made:
    Parameters.Of.Type<MyInterface>(ServiceKeys.ImplementationA));
```

#### Dependency condition

Dependency selects the consumer based on condition:

```
c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationA>(setup: Setup.With(
    condition: request => request.Parent.ServiceType == typeof(MyService2)));
```

#### Dependency is reused in resolution scope of specific consumer

It won't be Transient anymore, but it may be OK depending on your setup.

```
c.Register<MyService2>(setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));
c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationA>(Reuse.InResolutionScopeOf<MyService2>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your registration was ok

```
c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationA>(serviceKey: "implementationA");
c.Register<MyInterface, MyImplementationB>(serviceKey: "implementationB");
```

If you want to **Resolve** a concrete **Instance** for A or B, you can get it easier by this:

```
var a = c.Resolve<MyInterface>(serviceKey: "implementationA");
var b = c.Resolve<MyInterface>(serviceKey: "implementationB");
```