# DryIoc - specifying dependency when using constructor injection

Tags: dryioc

Using DryIoc if I register two implementations of the same contract - how can control which implementation to use when using constructor injection?

I see you can you register with a key or metadata - is it possible (using an attribute?) to control with implementation is injected? Or should I require a collection and figure out the correct implementation in the ctor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify what dependency to consume in constructor via Made.Of strongly-typed spec, like so:

```
container.Register<SomeClient>(Made.Of(
   () => new SomeClient(Arg.Of<IDep>("service key of impl")));
```

Here is the [related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612600/resolve-one-of-multiple-registrations-with-dryioc/34613963#34613963) with more options.

Attributed registration is supported via [MEF Attributed Model](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/Extensions/MefAttributedModel.md):

```
[Export]
public class SomeClient {
    public SomeClient([Import("x")]IDep dep) {}
}

[Export("x", typeof(IDep))]
public class X : IDep {}

[Export("y", typeof(IDep))]
public class Y : IDep {}

// in composition root:
using DryIoc.MefAttributedModel;

container = new Container().WithMefAttributedModel();

container.RegisterExports(
    typeof(SomeClient),
    typeof(X),
    typeof(Y));

container.Resolve<SomeClient>(); // will inject X
```

Comment: Link to wiki is broken

Comment: @Ceres fixed the wiki link