# How do I properly register default and scoped dependency for services in DryIoC

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I have `IDependency` dependency, that is used in a huge amount of services.
There are two implementations of this dependency: `DefaultDependency` and `CustomDependency`.
`DefaultDependency` in most of services. `CustomDependency` should be used in small amount of services.

Code example that is not working because of several factories:

```
var container = new Container();

container.Register<IDependency, DefaultDependency>(Reuse.ScopedOrSingleton);
container.Register<IService, Service>(Reuse.ScopedOrSingleton, setup: Setup.With(openResolutionScope: true));
container.Register<IDependency, CustomDependency>(Reuse.ScopedTo<IService>());
        
var service = (Service)container.Resolve<IService>(); // Throws Error.ExpectedSingleDefaultFactory
```

Is it possible to increase priority of scoped to factory for `CustomDependency` or something like that? Or the only way to achieve it is to register `DefaultDependency` as ScopedTo to all services that should use it?

Dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wPA19s

UPDATE:

I was able to make it work with FactoryMethod, but maybe there is some cleaner way:

```
container.Register<CustomDependency>(Reuse.ScopedOrSingleton);
container.Register<IService, Service>(made: Made.Of(
    factoryMethod: r => FactoryMethod.Of(typeof(Service).GetConstructorOrNull(args: new[] { typeof(IDependency) })),
    parameters: Parameters.Of.Type<IDependency>(requiredServiceType: typeof(CustomDependency))));
```

Dotnet fiddle with working resolving of `CustomDependency`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Znps9L

Comment: Make the constructors of those that require CustomDependency take a CustomDependency instead of IDependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the **dependency condition** from this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34613963/2492669

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructors of those that require `CustomDependency` take a `ICustomDependency` instead of `IDependency`.

```
interface ICustomDependency : IDependency {}

container.Register<IDependency, DefaultDependency>(Reuse.ScopedOrSingleton);
container.Register<ICustomDependency, CustomDependency>(Reuse.ScopedTo<IService>());

class ThatRequiresCustomDependency
{
     public ThatRequiresCustomDependency(ICustomDependency cd) {}
}
```

Comment: I am restricted to such changes, as I mentioned initially this interface is in use in many other services, so I am not able to change it